# linux/solaris kill many proccess with one command

Tags: linux, solaris, process, shell-scripting, kill

Is it possible to kill all find process with one command?

I do not want to kill each process as `kill -9 25295` , `kill -9 11994` , etc.. Rather, what I want is a simple way or command that kill all find process (my target is to perfrom this action on linux and solaris machines).

```
$ ps -ef | grep find 
root 25295 25290   0 08:59:59 pts/1 0:01 find /etc -type f -exec grep -l 100.106.23.152 {} ; -print
root 11994 26144   0 09:04:18 pts/1 0:00 find /etc -type f -exec grep -l 100.106.23.153 {} ; -print
root 25366 25356   0 08:59:59 pts/1 0:01 find /etc -type f -exec grep -l 100.106.23.154 {} ; -print
root 26703 26658   0 09:00:05 pts/1 0:01 find /etc -type f -exec grep -l 100.106.23.155 {} ; -print
```

Comment: Having answered some of your questions and looked at may others I think that rather than an Q&A site it's time to talk to your manager about getting some basic education in the tools that you are using.

Comment: @lain this would be so *old school*! Neat!

Comment: @lain what you think about the solution: fuser -k /tmp/test.sh ? , (for linux and solaris )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work on both Linux and Solaris and do precisely what you need:

```
pgrep -f 'find /etc'     # verify the listing before proceeding
pkill -9 -f 'find /etc'
```

In your situation, avoid `killall`. If you use it on Linux, sooner or later you will mistake the ssh sessions, run it on Solaris, creating unnecessary risk.

The `-f` option of pgrep/pkill means to match the entire command line. In case you need to match path of the program or script (`/var/tmp/test.sh`), this works if you had run it with the entire path. To be precise, you only need to escape the `.` so you need

`pkill -9 -f '/var/tmp/test\.sh'`

If you have run the same program as `./test.sh` you need to kill it as such. See `-f` option in `ps`.

Comment: Someday one of my coworker typed pkill -v foobar , thinking -v would increase verbosity;obviously it was on a production database server... Be careful everyone when you use pkill ;)

Comment: Moreover, `f` is very close to `v` on the keyboard :)

Comment: @kubanczyk what about fuser -k /tmp/test.sh - I think is the best solution for linux and solaris - what you think ?

Comment: @yael Never used fuser -k, because it does not support regular expressions as patterns. So I don't have any experience to share.

Comment: not sure I try to kill the programs /tmp/test.pl ( was 12 process running on both time ) , and fuser -k killed all (test.pl) process ,  ,

Answer (score 3):

Use `pkill find` which is a variant of `pgrep` (`process grep`). On Linux, `killall find` would also work.

Comment: is it possible to kill proccess as script for example - pkill /var/tmp/test.sh ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the killall command

```
killall find
```

Comment: But be _very_ careful if going between Linux and Solaris, because at least on older versions of SunOS that I used, `killall` literally _kills all processes_, without the process matching and selection of the Linux version.

Comment: As far as I know, this is still the case.

Comment: As a side note, the behavior is not nearly as funny on Solaris as on AIX. There, `killall` *doesn't* kill the current shell, so poor user has no idea how much fun just happened in the background :)