# Solaris' `killall`

Tags: solaris

This question is inspired by question [“linux/solaris kill many proccess with one command”](https://serverfault.com/questions/451950/linux-solaris-kill-many-proccess-with-one-command).

Solaris' `killall` is described there as killing every process without any name matching, as is the case on Linux. What are the use cases of such destructive behavior then? I don't think I ever needed such an action on my Linux installations…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the use cases of such destructive behavior then?

During shutdown, it will attempt to kill all remaining processes that haven't died yet (in an attempt to get them to clean up - since any form of cleanup is better than none).

I would agree that the Linux usage of `killall` has spoiled the Solaris version for us.